# http requests naming conventions with ajax / angularjs http requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, http

In angular when I use

```
$http.get(/users/' + userid).success(function (data, status) {
    });
};
```

and look at the request being made in the dev tools network tab the 'name' of this request will be whatever userid is.  If the path is just /users then the 'name' will be users.  However on some pages I have 3/4 requests going to different paths that use some sort of id so there are a number of requests that just have a number as their 'name' in the dev tools task.

Is there a way to make this name more descriptive or is there a best practice as far as that goes?  I am using chrome dev tools but I don't think this is browser specific I just would prefer to make this more descriptive no matter what browser or what dev tools are or aren't being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you can't change this. It's not angularJS specific, either, it's just the way chrome displays network requests.